# How to define when $compile service completely finish compiling in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have popup directive that inherits in $scope template witch is a string tamplate of popup's content that popup should display.

```
scope: {
   template: '=popInfo'//<div another directive></div>
}
```

This template string could contain itself a another directive so I'm using $compile service to compile it. Something like that:

```
$el.find('content-container').append($compile($scope.template)($scope));
$scope.makeVisible();//after i've compiled i'm making it visible
```

It works but exist side effect that looks like blinking.
First is showning popup container after that is showning content.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FehvteTvZ92e4MFZNaHj?p=preview - here is example. Seems that it's reprodused only with templateUrl.

Could anybody help me avoid such behaviour?

Comment: fiddle link please

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FehvteTvZ92e4MFZNaHj?p=preview here is the example, it seems that it's reproducing only with templateUrl but question is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a digest cycle. For instance make the element visible within a `$timeout` call:

```
$el.find('content-container').append($compile($scope.template)($scope));
$timeout($scope.makeVisible);

// or $timeout(function() { $scope.makeVisible(); });
```